# Ubuntu does not reach login screen

Tags: boot, login-screen

I belive I have accepted some updates yesterday and now my laptop doesn't reach the login screen. It keeps loading and showing the Ubuntu logo, but when I press on <kbd>F7</kbd> key it shows me the following errors:

[image]

Edit1:
I followed this solution [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076)
the `Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time` section
and i basically got the same issue, it tried to start few jobs, login services and network manager etc... but fails in all of them, i belive the network manager services is the one causing all of this, however, i switched on windows and also tried ubuntu from my usb and internet works just fine, so its not a hardware issue

Link to original image: [Shared album on Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipO6_pfPMJc6TrcyJz3Iu2tT95Q2NRgs5EqugDWv4Nm2UtQydc_WOlXaW-ugVKtjwA?key=Z0FGX1pSN01xS0twZmowVVJ6Q2hLNHMzdWU2VEtB)

Comment: i am not having a black screen .. i tried the suggested solutions but its not helping

Comment: "Black screen" also refers to virtual terminals which are mostly black due to their (default) background colour. Which answer(s) of the linked question did you try? It has many different answers after all. What *exactly* did you do and what happened?

Comment: i tried this section and the link it had about AMD `Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time`

Comment: But are you even trying to install Ubuntu? Your questions says that the problem occurred following a recent update. In the linked question there's a link “[If an update or something else caused your problem](/a/162078/175814)” to a suitable answer. Could you please refer to it to find a solution based on your system configuration (which you should include in your question in any case)?